# Best way to implement Nuget packages

Tags: c#, nuget

I'm making a complex application and I would create more little packages to include. I have installed a nuget package "CreateNugetPackageFromProjectAfterEachBuild" that create or update automatically a package of my application. In this moment I create two types of package Debug and Release but from VS15 I see only one package to install. Why? Is the correct way to work?

Thank you!

Comment: I actually don't understand your question. Could you please be more specific? Posting your nuspec file would be pretty helpful.

Comment: I'm not practical with a Nuget package and I don't know the right way to work. Only this. I would have some suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not clear from your question, what exactly you want to create NuGet packages for.

In any case, it makes no sense to have separate Release and Debug versions of packages. You could separate them by version, though:

- have stable releases built as Release
- have prereleases built as Debug

Make sure that each NuGet package you build has a different version, otherwise you'll cause yourself a lot of grief. NuGet has no way to differentiate between different packages with the same version. You can only update a package to a different version and individual versions are cached. It's best you create and publish new package versions from a build server, not directly from a development environment to avoid confusion.

Also, keep in mind that you should really only be using NuGet packages for libraries which have an independent lifecycle and are used in multiple projects. You will want stabilize a library before creating a new version of the package and then stick with this version in your application until you have a new stable version of the library ready.

If your libraries are more tightly coupled to the application - they don't have a separate lifecycle and you tend to modify them together with the application, then referencing them in the application as a NuGet package is not that good of an idea. You're better off just having both the libraries and the application as part of the same solution.

Comment: Is correct add Pdb files in the package? Because I would debug from my "Main" application.

Comment: Usually not. The suggested way would be to put them in a [symbols package](https://docs.nuget.org/create/creating-and-publishing-a-symbol-package). Alternatively, you might want to take a look at [GitLink](https://oren.codes/2015/09/23/enabling-source-code-debugging-for-your-nuget-packages-with-gitlink/).